# Split master spreads into pages in Adobe Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm currently working on a document that consists of multiple master spreads, but I'm looking for a way to split these spreads into individual pages.

Is this possible, or do I have to do it manually by copying artwork etc. to the new master?

Comment: Welcome to GraphicDesign and let us know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 1):

If the question is "how do I display spreads as individual pages" this can be done by unchecking "allow document pages to shuffle" then dragging single pages to their own areas.

[image: inDesign page display adjustment]

Answer (score 0):

I might not get exactly what you're asking, but is it solved by right clicking in the master pages area, select "New Master...", and then just select the "Based on Master" to create the new one?

Like in the third line in the image below?

[image]